# Count subselect elements according to parent id

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mariadb

I'm having this MySQL Query

```
            SELECT
                    t1.article_id,
                    t1.user_id,
                    t1.like_date,
                    (
                        SELECT
                                COUNT(*)
                            FROM liketbl t2
                            WHERE
                                t1.article_id=t2.article_id
                ) as totallike
            FROM    liketbl t1
            WHERE
                user_id = 1;
```

I need to get article id, user id and liked date in one run with the number of total entries.
Subselect is, in my opinion the easiest was to achieve this.
(Don't want to run several queries in client entviroment.
But is not working.
Don't know why, help is appreceated.

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: Recommendation: Always count a specific element, this makes your queries faster, particularly if you are joining tables during a count, because the server doesn't have to guess what you are counting (although, in this example, it is not needed).

Comment: @Svip, the recommendation is just vice versa: COUNT(*) will never be slower than COUNT(column), but might be faster, because COUNT(column) has to check every row for NULL. And of course, the result might be different.

Comment: @Dnoeth: That depends on whether it is a stored procedure or not.

Comment: @Svip, could you elaborate why it's different in a SP?

Comment: @dnoeth: Firstly; you obviously count a field that cannot be null (such an id).  Secondly, if you've chosen a specific field and you have multiple tables, it doesn't have to guess which table it is counting on; which means listening on fields you might have no interest in.  And in a stored procedure, it doesn't have to guess based on the call; because the stored procedure is already compiled.  (Of course, if the stored procedure is bad, then so will the run time be, but that's a different story all together.)

Comment: @Svip: "it doesn't have to guess which table it is counting", if there's the result of a join there's no table anymore, it's just a set of rows. COUNT(*) allows an optimzer to pick the best plan to get the desired result. And an ID might be NULL as a result of an outer join. So my basic rule always was: unless you actually need a non-NULL count of a column always use COUNT(*)

Comment: @dnoeth: In my experience, the optimiser is not always perfect, particularly with complicated table joins and indexes.  But I suppose you are right, that in general, it will be good enough (or better than the alternative) for people to just use `COUNT()` (is `COUNT()` different from `COUNT(*)`, btw?).

Comment: @Svip: There's no COUNT(), just COUNT(*), the forum software removed the star, cause it's used to format text in italics. Reminder: never use two asterisks in one comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT  t1.article_id,
        t1.user_id,
        t1.like_date,
        COUNT(*) as totallike
FROM liketbl t1 inner join liketbl t2 on t1.article_id=t2.article_id
WHERE user_id = 1
group by t1.article_id,t1.user_id,t1.like_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to filter on `user_id = 1` in the subquery to get what you expect.

The `where` only operates on the outer select.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 SELECT
                    t1.article_id,
                    t1.user_id,
                    t1.like_date,
                    count(SELECT * FROM liketbl t2 WHERE
                                t1.article_id=t2.article_id ) as totallike
            FROM    liketbl t1
            WHERE
                user_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Scalar Subqueries tend to be the worst case, it's usually more efficient to rewrite them.

Depending on the number of rows in both tables this is another approach using a Derived Table:

```
SELECT
   t1.article_id
   ,t1.user_id
   .t1.like_date
   ,t2.totallike
FROM liketbl t1
JOIN
 (
   SELECT
      article_id
      ,COUNT(*) AS totallike
   FROM liketbl
   GROUP BY article_id
 ) AS t2
ON t1.article_id=t2.article_id
WHERE
   user_id = 1;
```